# CSS: Menu with dropdown same line as the rest + IE

Tags: css

```
    <div id="menu">
    <ul class="menu">
          <li><a href="home.php">TEM</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">TEM</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">TEM</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">TEM</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">TEM</a></li>
    </ul>
    <img src="images/button.png" width="126" height="23" class="menu_class">
    <ul class="the_menu">
    <li><a href="#">Profil</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Inställningar</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Vänner</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Bildgalleri</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Diskoteker</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Evenemanger</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

HTML

CSS:

```
.menu_class {
    border:1px solid #1c1c1c;
}

.the_menu {

    position:absolute; 
    display:none;
    width:150px;
    border: 1px solid #1c1c1c;
}

.the_menu li {
    background-color: #283d44;
}

.the_menu li a {
    color:#FFFFFF; 
    text-decoration:none; 
    padding:10px; 
    display:block;
}
  
.the_menu li a:hover {
    padding:10px;
    font-weight:bold;
    color: #fffc30;
}
#menu{
    float: right;
    list-style: none;
    margin-top: 10px;
    padding: 0;
}
.menu li {
    float: left;
    font-size: 12px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
.menu a {
    color: #94938e;
    display: block;
    float: left;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 10px;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-weight: bold;
}

.menu a:hover {
    color: #f7f400;
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

What i would like to do: Having the menu with the dropdown besides the other "TEM" menu links

What happens in FF: It kinda do like a 
 for the menu, why I cant figure out

What happens in IE: It places the menu where i want it to be although when i do mouseover(when the <ul class=the_menu appears), it shows it another place

image for issue:
[![http://i36.tinypic.com/e8ptl3.png][1]][1]

http://i36.tinypic.com/e8ptl3.png
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/zBV6R.png

Hope you can help me out, im lost..

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_positioning.asp

1. Your absolutely positioned element needs a parent (or an ancestor) with a "position: relative;" to know where to be positioned. Since you didn't put one, it's hard for the browsers to determine where to put the element, and each does it in a different way.
2. Once you've set "position: relative;", you can set top or bottom, left or right on the absolutely positioned element, to offset it.

Hope this helps.